# Woocommerce $product->is_on_sale() always returns true

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have the code below in functions.php for a child theme.  The idea is that if a user books a job online they get a discount on the job to encourage more online bookings and is showing like this in the store:

Walk-In Price: £349.99
Online Price: £339.00

However, $product->is_on_sale() always seems to return true even if I leave the Sale Price blank in the product.  If I only have a normal price (no sale price) then this displays nothing (i.e no price is shown, its left blank) and I want to show the normal price.

```
// ***********************************************************
// START ADD TEXT BEFORE SALE PRICE
// && (!has_term( 'product', 'product_cat'))
// ***********************************************************
function bd_rrp_sale_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    
    // SHOWS PRICE FOR PRODUCTS NOT REPAIRS
    if (has_term( 'Products', 'product_cat'))
    {
        if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) 
        {
            $has_sale_text = array(
              '<del>' => '<del>Normal Price: ',
              '<ins>' => '<br>Sale Price: <ins>'  );
            
            $return_string = str_replace(array_keys( $has_sale_text ), array_values( $has_sale_text ), $price);
        }
        else 
        {
            $return_string = $price;// . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$product->get_regular_price();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) 
        {
            $has_sale_text = array(
              '<del>' => '<del>Walk-In Price: ',
              '<ins>' => '<br>Online Price: <ins>'
            );
            
            $return_string = str_replace(array_keys( $has_sale_text ), array_values( $has_sale_text ), $price);
        }
        else 
        {
            $retun_string = "2";// $price;
        }
    }//ENDIF
    
  return $return_string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bd_rrp_sale_price_html', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: There is an undefined variabe in your code. In the else -> else condition replace `$retun_string` with `$return_string`

Comment: @7uc1f3r thank you... its been bugging me for months...  and I missed this every time.

Comment: p.s. note to oneself - enable debugger next time!